# express-rate-limit with static

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, express-rate-limit

I have VPS with express and react bundle.
The problem is that I get the same IP address (localhost) when I access the API from the frontend, therefore I cannot correctly use the express-rate-limit.

I have an express server:

```
const apiLimiter = rateLimit({
  windowMs: 1 * 60 * 1000,
  max: 30
});

app.use("/api/", apiLimiter);

app.use(express.static('client/build'));
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
});
```

and proxy config in package.json of frontend:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:3000/"
```

How to fix it and use express-rate-limit correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Per https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-rate-limit#usage

`app.set('trust proxy', 1)`

Comment: Going to need a lot more details then. Trust proxy will only work if your webserver is sending the correct headers. What's you stack and I assuming your going from HTTPS to HTTP via the webserver proxy? How are you testing this? Does it work in dev?